# Get the top followed followers of a user in twitter using python-twitter

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I want to get the top followed followers of a user in twitter using python-twitter. And that without getting the 'Rate limit exceeded' error message.

I can get followers of a user then get the number of folowers of each one, but the problem is when that user is big (thousands).

I use the following function to get the followers ids of a particular user:

```
def GetFollowerIDs(self, userid=None, cursor=-1):
   url = 'http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json'
   parameters = {}
   parameters['cursor'] = cursor
   if userid:
       parameters['user_id'] = userid
   json = self._FetchUrl(url, parameters=parameters)
   data = simplejson.loads(json)
   self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
   return data
```

and my code is:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='XXXX',
                  consumer_secret='XXXXX',
                  access_token_key='XXXXX',
                  access_token_secret='XXXXXX')
user=api.GetUser(screen_name="XXXXXX")
users=api.GetFollowerIDs(user)

#then i make a request per follower in users so that I can sort them according to the number of followers.
```

the problem is that when the user has a lot of followers i get the 'Rate limit exceeded' error message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the results in chunks as explained in [this link](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/wiki/Rate-Limited-API---How-to-deal-with).

This is the work around currently shown on the github page. But if you would want an unlimited stream, you should upgrade the subscription for your twitter application.

```
def GetFollowerIDs(self, userid=None, cursor=-1, count = 10):
   url = 'http://twitter.com/followers/ids.json'
   parameters = {}
   parameters['cursor'] = cursor
   if userid:
       parameters['user_id'] = userid
   remaining = count
   while remaining > 1:
       remaining -= 1
       json = self._FetchUrl(url, parameters=parameters)
       try:
           data = simplejson.loads(json)
           self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
       except twitterError:
           break
   return data

def main():
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='XXXX',
                      consumer_secret='XXXXX',
                      access_token_key='XXXXX',
                      access_token_secret='XXXXXX')
    user=api.GetUser(screen_name="XXXXXX")
    count = 100 # you can find optimum value by trial & error
    while(#users not empty):
        users=api.GetFollowerIDs(user,count)
```

Or another possibility might be to try running Cron jobs in intervals as explained here.
http://knightlab.northwestern.edu/2014/03/15/a-beginners-guide-to-collecting-twitter-data-and-a-bit-of-web-scraping/

> Construct your scripts in a way that cycles through your API keys to stay within the rate limit.
>
> ---
>
> Cronjobs — A time based job scheduler that lets you run scripts at designated times or intervals (e.g. always at 12:01 a.m. or every 15 minutes).